# Select Unique Record from List based on Particular value In Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ. I have a list in which there some duplicate record based on a particular column value . I want to get unique record based on particular value from a list using Linq .
I am using distict method to get the unique record but it is not supported.
Here is my code.

```
        private List<CountOnlineUserModel> GetUserList()
        {

            List<CountOnlineUserModel> Users = new List<CountOnlineUserModel>();
            CountOnlineUserModel p = new CountOnlineUserModel();

            p.UserUniqueID = "IMW3";
            p.Username = "Rahul";
            Users.Add(p);

            p.UserUniqueID = "IMW4";
            p.Username = "Raheem";
            Users.Add(p);

            p.UserUniqueID = "IMW3";
            p.Username = "Rahul";
            Users.Add(p);

            p.UserUniqueID = "IMW4";
            p.Username = "Raheem";
            Users.Add(p);

            return Users;
        }
```

Comment: Where is your code? All you are showing is an attempt to generate what I assume is test data but you are using the same instance of `CountOnlineUserModel` so I don't think it is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: `CountOnlineUserModel` might be a struct, in which this works. @JasonBoyd

Comment: @Sweeper Valid point.

Comment: Try using GroupBy : Users.GroupBy(x => new  { name = x.Username, id = x.UserUniqueID }).Distinct().Select(x => new CountOnlineUserModel() { Username = x.Key.name, UserUniqueID = x.Key.id}).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do GroupBy:

```
return Users.GroupBy(c => c.UserUniqueID).Select(c => c.First()).ToList();
```

Make sure to add this on your using statements if you want to use GroupBy or Distinct:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing `IEquatable<CountOnlineUserModel>` in `CountOnlineUserModel`.

```
public class CountOnlineUserModel : IEquatable<CountOnlineUserModel> {
    // ...

    public bool Equals(CountOnlineUserModel other) {
        return UserUniqueID == other.UserUniqueID;
        // use the above if you just want to compare the IDs. Use below if you want to compare both the ID and name
        return UserUniqueID == other.UserUniqueID && 
            Username == other.Username;
    }
}
```

Now you can do `Distinct`:

```
        CountOnlineUserModel p = new CountOnlineUserModel();

        p.UserUniqueID = "IMW3";
        p.Username = "Rahul";
        Users.Add(p);

        p = new CountOnlineUserModel();
        p.UserUniqueID = "IMW4";
        p.Username = "Raheem";
        Users.Add(p);

        p = new CountOnlineUserModel();
        p.UserUniqueID = "IMW3";
        p.Username = "Rahul";
        Users.Add(p);

        p = new CountOnlineUserModel();
        p.UserUniqueID = "IMW4";
        p.Username = "Raheem";
        Users.Add(p);
        Console.WriteLine(Users.Distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy()`.

```
List<CountOnlineUserModel> distinctOnlineUsers = GetUserList()
  .GroupBy(p => p.UserUniqueID)
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

You can groups on multiple properties as well, can be done as follows:

```
List<CountOnlineUserModel> distinctOnlineUsers = GetUserList()
  .GroupBy(p => new {p.UserUniqueID, p.Username} )
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your sample data is messed up. You have created a list containing four references, all to the same object (whose properties you set once and then overwrite three times). Unless you are doing something pretty unusual, you have to instantiate a new object for each entry:

```
private List<CountOnlineUserModel> GetUserList()
{
    var users = new List<CountOnlineUserModel>
        {
            new CountOnlineUserModel
                {
                    UserUniqueID = "IMW3",
                    Username = "Rahul"
                },
            new CountOnlineUserModel
                {
                    UserUniqueID = "IMW3",
                    Username = "Rahul"
                },
            new CountOnlineUserModel
                {
                    UserUniqueID = "IMW4",
                    Username = "Raheem"
                },
            new CountOnlineUserModel
                {
                    UserUniqueID = "IMW3",
                    Username = "Rahul"
                }
        }
}
```

Second, I think you may be overthinking the problem. With the sample data you have provided, if you just want one of the records that matches on a particular value, you don't need distinct or group by.  Just take the first record that matches.

```
var record = users.Where( u => u.UserUniqueID == "IMW3" ).First();
```